# WCT Testing Polymer Examples

Tags: polymer, wct

Just discovered how powerful WCT testing is.  Should have been doing it a long time ago.  We use 100% Polymer for SPAs without any other frameworks.

Seems there would be a need for examples of how to test typical features of a Polymer App or element.  Does such a guide exist?

Comment: Isn't the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests) enough?

Comment: I miss too bether guide and documentation for using WCT